# Using React-native GDrive can't upload file to Google Drive

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api, access-token

I have used react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper in my project, I can log in successfully but still, I can't create or upload anything on google drive. What am I missing?

```
    signIn = async () => {
    try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const token= (await GoogleSignin.getTokens()).accessToken;

      // console.log();

      this.setState({ userInfo  : userInfo, accToken: token, email : userInfo.user.email});

      // alert('info is  '+ userInfo.user.familyName);

      GDrive.setAccessToken(this.state.accToken);
      GDrive.init();
      // alert("gdrive done")
      if(GDrive.isInitialized()){
        alert("Google Drive is Initialized Now!!")

        const contents = "My text file contents";
        GDrive.files.createFileMultipart(
             contents,
             "text/plain", {
               parents: ["root"],
               name: "text2.txt"
             },
             false);

        // this.createAFile();
      }

    } catch (error) {
      alert('error is '+ error);}
```

What am I missing? is this the right way to access the accessToken, or there is some other mistake, please help.

after  console.log(JSON.stringify(response)) I Get

```
     LOG  {"type":"default","status":403,"ok":false,"headers":{"map": 
     {"content- 
     type"
     :"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"Origin, X-                           
     Origin","date":"Wed, 22 Apr
      2020 14:33:41 GMT","www-authenticate":"Bearer          
     realm=\"https://accounts.google.c
     om/\", error=insufficient_scope,          
     scope=\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive\"
     ","server":"UploadServer","alt-svc":"quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000;          
     v=\"46,43\",h3-Q
     050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-         
     Q048=\":443\"; ma=25920
     00,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-         
     T050=\":443\"; m
     a=2592000","content-length":"306","x-guploader-         
     uploadid":"AAANsUm9Zk5l-FX8wKLBku
     ZUaYyxfMr403jozVOIj8Q7zt5AGORvLIEw0hUjNSfUsaiMt06LBTkJDa9SwzB98QCjkR8"}},"url"         :"
     https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?         
     uploadType=multipart","_bodyIni
     t":{"_data":{"size":306,"offset":0,"blobId":"29e54a64-a7cd-4b5b-8c2f-         
     6fe63d9391f
     b","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data"         
     {"size":306,"offset":0,"blobId":"29e5
     4a64-a7cd-4b5b-8c2f-6fe63d9391fb","__collector":{}}}}
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are receiving?

Comment: please share the link to the API wrapper you used. gspread right?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper this is the link to that api wrapper

Comment: And the error you are receiving?

Comment: It is 403 error , when I JSON.stringify(response) , this is what I get. 
 {"type":"default","status":403,"ok":false,"headers":{"map":{"content-type"
:"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"Origin, X-Origin","date":"Wed, 22 Apr
 2020 14:33:41 GMT","www-authenticate":"Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.c
om/\", error=insufficient_scope, scope=\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive\"
","server":"UploadServer","alt-svc":"quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q
050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=25920
}

Comment: I can't upload full error in comments

Comment: I have edited my question and also provided the error, please let me know if you can solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error:

> error=insufficient_scope, scope=\"googleapis.com/auth/drive\"

it appears that you did not grant the app access to the scope `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"`.

---

For creating files in Drive you need the app user's consent to that scope.

Verify that you are requesting access to that scope when you request the auth token.

---

**Example:**

You are using `GoogleSignin` so pass the scope option into `GoogleSignin.configure()` before requesting the access token.

```js
GoogleSignin.configure({
scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
...
});
```

**Documentation:**
[Drive API v3 scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#drive)

Comment: how am I suppose to verify ?

Comment: `GoogleSignin.getTokens()` on this function

Comment: GoogleSignin.configure() takes options, one of which is the scope(s)

Comment: I have defined the scopes as defined in the link., What should I particularly define here?

Comment: Ok I will have it a try , and will tell you if the problem solved.

Comment: did you change the scope from "`auth/drive.readonly`" to "`auth/drive`" ?

Comment: It Worked THANK YOUU SOOOO MUCHHHH!!!!!!!!, I was writing GoogleSignin.configure({ scopes:['googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'], but after removing readonly, it worked .. THANKS MAN!